# dc Line chart not highlighting properly in Firefox on legend hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

If you open this [link](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite.html) in Chrome and hover on legends, it works fine. But if you open the same link in Firefox, something weird happens and line chart is not highlighting properly. In my personal code, I tried to explicitly add highlight class to the hovered line using the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < subchartIds.length; i++) {
    if (subchartIds[i] === highlightedId) {
        var el = chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i] + ' .chart-body .stack-list')._groups[0][0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
        el.className.animVal += ' highlight';
        el.className.baseVal += ' highlight';
    } else {
        chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i]).style("opacity", function () {
            return 0.2;
        });    
    }        
}
```

where subchartIds array have IDs of number of line charts in my composite chart and highlightedId contains the ID of line chart I want to highlight i.e. line chart belonging to legend on which mouse is hovered.

Comment: The legend works for me in Firefox 64 & 65. It's kind of weird, but the legend actually uses the color value to match legend items with chart items. Since the example just uses "red" and "blue" it's hard to figure how that could go wrong. Could you share more details about which version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: @Gordon I'm using Firefox 64. Though the problem is solved now. I removed all the default properties on legend hover and then reassigned them explicitly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Gordon I added the code sample which solved this issue, you can take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time on it, I was able to solve it by first removing all the default properties which were set on **path** element, then reassigning required attributes myself.

```
for (var i = 0; i < subchartIds.length; i++) {
    chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i]).style("opacity", function () {
    return 1;
    });
    var localElement = chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i] + ' .chart-body .stack-list')._groups[0][0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
    localElement.className.animVal = localElement.className.animVal.replace('highlight','');
    localElement.className.baseVal = localElement.className.baseVal.replace('highlight','');
    localElement.className.animVal = localElement.className.animVal.replace('fadeout','');
    localElement.className.baseVal = localElement.className.baseVal.replace('fadeout','');
}
for (var i = 0; i < subchartIds.length; i++) {
    if (subchartIds[i] === highlightedId) {
        var elementToHighlight = chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i] + ' .chart-body .stack-list')._groups[0][0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
        elementToHighlight.className.animVal += ' highlight';
        elementToHighlight.className.baseVal += ' highlight';
        chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i]).style("opacity", function () {
            return 0.9;
        });    
    } else {
        var elementToFade = chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i] + ' .chart-body .stack-list')._groups[0][0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
        elementToFade.className.animVal += ' fadeout';
        elementToFade.className.baseVal += ' fadeout';
        chartObject.select('g.sub._' + subchartIds[i]).style("opacity", function () {
            return 0.2;
        });
    }        
}
```